# Elasticsearch restore indicies from data-node snapshot files only

Tags: elasticsearch

I was upgrading from Elasticsearch 7.10 to 8.4. I wanted to make a Filesystem snapshot, copy the data, install a new version and restore the data from the snapshot files I created earlier.
I have a setup with two node roles: `master` and `data`.

I didn't know that, in such a setup, when Elastic is making a Filesystem snapshot, it'll create a structure with raw indices on the data node, something like this:

```
indicies/
  8wPAc89lSrqFunOTSkShSQ/
    0/
      __LHqdmaHLQU6WWpJVlqFY4w
      index-AXVMDc2DQZyBZihEeGOM9g
      snap-7Mv54vkoRjS9YLLgSaokDw.dat
      ...
  I25vR794SZmFJ3TvjF3d-Q/
    0/
      __-f2Sb1onSlaj9XSAhc84LQ
      index-sc-iDaI7TRGX0BKg7Mzk2w
      snap-7Mv54vkoRjS9YLLgSaokDw.dat
```

and a structure with some metadata on the master node, like this:

```
index-0
index.latest
indicies/
  I25vR794SZmFJ3TvjF3d-Q/
    0/
    meta-oHtfvYQBIjpWMF5xqR1L.dat
meta-7Mv54vkoRjS9YLLgSaokDw.dat
snap-7Mv54vkoRjS9YLLgSaokDw.dat
```

When I was copying the files, I **only copied the ones from the `data` node** (not knowing that Elasticsearch is also writing metadata information to the `master` node). So I now have raw indices data without metadata information for it.

I wanted to re-create some of the metadata (`index-0` is a JSON with some mapping) by myself but there are also some encoded files for each snapshot so I assume they're probably some calculated control hashes and my approach might not work.

Is there a way to restore all these indices in Elasticsearch without the metadata information?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to rebuild the metadata without knowing what all needs to go in there.

Also between 7.10 to 8.4 there has been significant changes in the index format and you will probably not be able to get 8.4 to read your 7.10 raw files without any issues.

Also when upgrading from 7.x to 8.4, you must first [upgrade to 7.17](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/8.4/upgrading-elastic-stack.html#prepare-to-upgrade) before upgrading to 8.4.